# Is it possible to use DataFrame.replace in a dataframe with tuples?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

toy_df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [('Hello','Sarah!'),('Bye', 'my', 'dear', 'Beth')]})

toy_dict = {('Hello','Sarah!') : ('oh,', 'you', 'again'), ('Bye', 'my', 'dear', 'Beth'):('xoxo',)}

print(toy_df.replace(toy_dict))
```

But I got `TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'tuple'`.

From what I was able to understand, tuples inside dataframes are treated as objects, not tuples. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use applymap function:

import pandas as pd

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [('Hello', 'Sarah!'), ('Bye', 'my', 'dear', 'Beth')]})
toy_dict = {('Hello', 'Sarah!'): ('oh,', 'you', 'again'), ('Bye', 'my', 'dear', 'Beth'): ('xoxo',)}

new_toy_df = toy_df.applymap(lambda x: toy_dict[x] if x in toy_dict else x)
print(new_toy_df)
```

output:

```
               col0
0  (oh,, you, again)
1            (xoxo,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which replaces with `NaN` any values not found in the dictionary:

```
toy_df.assign(col0 = [toy_dict.get(x, np.nan) for x in toy_df['col0']])
```

Output:

```
                col0
0  (oh,, you, again)
1            (xoxo,)
```